# NodeJs get JSON for each url request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, for-loop

Hello i created an JSON downloader with nodeJS if use one url this works fine , the problem begins if i try create several JSON files from an url array, the JSON name should be equal to used url any suggestions?
Thanks

im using 2 npm modules

```
var request = require("request");

var fs = require('fs');

var url =[
    "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
    "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
    "http://ip.jsontest.com/"
]
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        fs.writeFile("de.json", JSON.stringify(response), function(err){
            if(err){console.log(err);} else {console.log("create"  + url + 'JSON ');}
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: is it possible to pass array of urls to request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`request`](https://github.com/request/request) does not support arrays, you need to use loops

From doc: `uri || url - fully qualified uri or a parsed url object from url.parse()`

```
var request = require("request");

var fs = require('fs');

var urls =[
    "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
    "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
    "http://ip.jsontest.com/"
];

urls.forEach(function (url) {
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            fs.writeFile("de.json", JSON.stringify(response), function(err){
                if(err){console.log(err);} else {console.log("create"  + url + 'JSON ');}
            });
        }
    })
});
```